# What does !>> mean?

Tags: if-statement, operators, lasso-lang

I ran across a bit of if-statement code today in Lasso that I hadn't seen before. It looked like this:

```
if(#theFile !>> 'image');
    ...
/if;
```

How does the !>> operator work in Lasso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference information for this operator in Lasso 8.5 is here[[1]](http://reference.lassosoft.com/Reference.LassoApp?1113).

In Lasso 9, you can find the discussion about "Containment Operators" here[[2]](http://www.lassosoft.com/Language-Guide-Operators).

Discussing Lasso 9, in the expression

`E1 >> E2`

this is useful if the type of `E1` includes a `contains` method, whose only parameter will be populated by the right operand; `E2` in the example just above.  This operator invokes that method for `E1` with argument `E2`.  That method returns a boolean value, so this operator returns a boolean operator.

`E1 !>> E2`

yields the same result as

`!(E1 >> E2)`

Example:

`!("test" >> "st") == ("test" !>> "st")`

Result:

`true`

Answer (score 1):

It refers to `NOT CONTAINS`

Refer to link for more [lasso reference](http://reference.lassosoft.com/Reference.LassoApp?6998)

Comment: You have all the Symbols down the page.

Comment: My mistake, but the other answer was more detailed. Thanks for your response.